# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10

Tags: java, maven

I have this error when attempting to `install` the maven project:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only
>   (analyze-only) on project functional-tests: Dependency
>   problems found -> [Help 1]

It appears right after the integration tests, during the `verify` phase. I can hardly guess where to look as not much other information is provided by the logs. I tried to run maven with `-X` argument to have a deeper look but that's the only error that appears. The last thing I see before the error appears in the detailed log is this WARNING below (that I doubt has anything to do with the error):

```
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:test
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.090 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-28T10:58:54+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 60M/1042M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (analyze-only) on project functional-tests: Dependency problems found -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (analyze-only) on project functional-tests: Dependency problems found
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (analyze-only) on project functional-tests: Dependency problems found
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Dependency problems found
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.analyze.AbstractAnalyzeMojo.execute(AbstractAnalyzeMojo.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

What could be causing this issue?

**UPDATE**:
I have resolved the issues that caused the warnings above and it did help removing the error. Now I only wonder why having used undeclared dependencies or declared unused dependencies are causing the whole build to fail?

**UPDATE2**:
Changing the `slf4j` scope to `runtime` also solved the problem.

Comment: `used undeclared dependencies found`  means that this dependency is transitive. Declare it in pom.xml. `Unused declared
dependencies found` means that this dependency is declared in pom.xml but it's not used. Just remove it from pom.xml

Comment: @JaySmith Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes, I know what these mean but didn't think that they are the reason for getting the error and failing the build. Having said that, I did resolve these warnings and the build finished successfully (please see the update). I'd really like to understand why what seems to be minor warnings caused the whole build to fail.

Comment: Put back the configuration that generate the problem and run maven with `-e -X` parameters, they are errors and debug respectively so you will see what caused the problem. Perhaps an underlying exception?

Comment: @JorgeCampos thanks for your comment. I mentioned in my question that I did run it with `-X` and the error appears straight after the warnings. I just added a more detailed log to the question. Also, I just managed to resolve the error by changing the package scope to `runtime` instead of the default `compile`.

Comment: Accordingly to the provided link on [MojoExecutionException](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException) It is an exception launched by a plugin which means that perhaps the plugin that thrown the warning may be signaling the build to fail in a bogusly way.

Comment: Just make sure of a configuration `<failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>` if you don't want to fail for warnings. That worked for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently the used undeclared dependencies warning **was** the culprit of my problem. After adding the dependency explicitly to the pom file, the issue was resolved.

Comment: My problem is even weirder. Local master build fails the same as my feature branch, however coworker's master works, and when he pulled my feature branch it didn't. I add a dependency to my local master / feature branch and they both pass. Wtf.

Answer (score 11):

The reason of this  is:

```
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:test
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.6:compile
```

you should remove `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` dependency and add `javax.activation:activation` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, got same problem (few times for last few months) and found that fixing all warnings with Used undeclared dependencies/Unused declared dependencies fixes the issue.